# Docker container disappears upon exiting

Tags: docker, ubuntu

The container was created with the commands

```
docker run --gpus '"'device=$CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'"' --ipc=host --rm -it \
    --mount src=$(pwd),dst=/clipbert,type=bind \
    --mount src=$OUTPUT,dst=/storage,type=bind \
    --mount src=$PRETRAIN_DIR,dst=/pretrain,type=bind,readonly \
    --mount src=$TXT_DB,dst=/txt,type=bind,readonly \
    --mount src=$IMG_DIR,dst=/img,type=bind,readonly \
    -e NVIDIA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=$CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES \
    -w /clipbert jayleicn/clipbert:latest \
    bash -c "source /clipbert/setup.sh && bash" \
```

But upon exit and running `docker ps -a`, the container is not listed and it seems like the container is only temporarily created. This has not happened in my previous experience with docker, what may the reason be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `--rm` options tells docker run command to remove the container when it exits automatically.